# Using sed command convert only first character in specific line with uppercase

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I convert the first character of each word in the line after `gr-description:`  to uppercase?

For example :

```
$ cat /tmp/test1
groMail:
test@xyz.com
gr-description:
abc-location-999
group-emailid:
abclocation999@xyz.com
members:
abc@xyz.com
abcd@xyz.com
abc.abc@xyz.com
```

Output should be

```
groMail:
test@xyz.com
gr-description:
Abc-Location-999
group-emailid:
abclocation999@xyz.com
members:
abc@xyz.com
abcd@xyz.com
abc.abc@xyz.com
```

I tried the command below command but I am unable to merge

```
sed -n '/gr-description:/{n;p;}' grp1 | sed 's/\<./\u&/g'
```

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be using GNU `sed` or another version with the `\u` extension, so you can do this:

```
sed -e '/gr-description/{n;s/\b./\u&/g;}' < test1
```

This matches lines containing `gr-description`, and then runs everything in the [`{}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-g_t_0040_007b_0040_007d-command-grouping-100) at that point. [`n`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-n-_0028next_002dline_0029-command-97) goes to the next line, printing the one we just matched, and then the [`s`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) command replaces all characters that follow a word boundary ([`\b` or `\<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-g_t_0040acronym_007bGNU_007d-extensions_002c-special-escapes-221)) with their upper-cased version ([`\u&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Parenthesized-substrings-104)).

This does it all in one go, without piping one `sed` into another, which wouldn't do what you wanted - you were only getting the one line out, rather than editing the stream as you go.

Comment: Thanks Terdon.                                            Thank you very much Michael for the solution.